# Multiple thread using ThreadPool and use of CountdownEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading

i got a example of `CountdownEvent` usage but when i go through the sample code then i just do not understand what it is doing and how `CountdownEvent`'s `Signal() and AddCount()` help to synchronization for multiple thread.

here is the sample. please some one help me to understand how synchronization is working for multiple thread in this example where `Signal() and AddCount()` used.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (CountdownEvent e = new CountdownEvent(1))
        {
            // fork work: 
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5;i++ )
            {
                // Dynamically increment signal count.
                TaskInfo ti = new TaskInfo("Current Thread ", i);
                Console.WriteLine("Running thread " + e.CurrentCount);
                e.AddCount();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //ProcessData(state);
                        TaskInfo inner_ti = (TaskInfo)state;
                        //Console.WriteLine(inner_ti.Boilerplate + inner_ti.Value);
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Signal thread " + e.CurrentCount);
                        e.Signal();
                    }
                },
                 ti);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Outer Signal thread " + e.CurrentCount);
            e.Signal();

            // The first element could be run on this thread. 

            // Join with work.
            Console.WriteLine("Wait thread ");
            e.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("ReadLine..... ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

public class TaskInfo
{
    // State information for the task.  These members 
    // can be implemented as read-only properties, read/write 
    // properties with validation, and so on, as required. 
    public string Boilerplate;
    public int Value;

    // Public constructor provides an easy way to supply all 
    // the information needed for the task. 
    public TaskInfo(string text, int number)
    {
        Boilerplate = text;
        Value = number;
    }
}
```

just guide me with small sample code like how `Signal() and AddCount()` is used in real life scenario for thread synchronization. thanks

Comment: You already have the code sample.  Maybe you'll understand it if you replace Signal() with SubtractCount().  When the Wait() returns, you have a guarantee that it counted down to 0.  Which provides you with the guarantee that all threadpool threads finished their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job of `CountdownEvent` is to provide a waitable object (i.e. an object that will block the current thread on request until some condition is satisfied), where the condition that needs to be satisfied is for the object's internal counter to reach the value of `0`.

The code you've shown will initialize the `CountdownEvent` object with a count of `1`. This value represents the main thread itself; the main thread will call `Signal()` later, indicating that it's completed its own work (which is to start five other threads).

For each new task that is created, the main thread increments — by calling the `AddCount()` method — the `CountdownEvent` object's counter by one before starting that new task (in this case, by queuing the task to the global thread pool). Each task, as it completes, will then decrement the object's counter by calling the `Signal()` method.

So initially, the code is repeatedly increasing the counter, from its initial value of `1`, to its maximum value of `6`.

Immediately after the tasks have been queued, the main thread decrements the counter to `5`. Each task, as it completes, decrements the counter again. Five tasks means decrementing the counter five times, so when the last task completes, the counter will reach `0`.

Remember: the point of the `CountdownEvent` object is to release a thread that is waiting on it when its internal counter reaches `0`. (Or more specifically, for the waitable object to be set to its signaled, non-blocking state).

The main thread calls the `Wait()` method on the `CountdownEvent` object, which initially causes the main thread to be blocked (i.e. to wait). It will continue to wait until the `CountdownEvent` is set to the non-blocking state, which occurs when its internal counter reaches `0`, which occurs when the last task completes.

Thus, the main thread waits until the last task completes.

> just guide me with small sample code like how Signal() and AddCount() is used in real life scenario for thread synchronization

The code example you've posted here seems "real" enough. My description above explains how the code example works. You would use the `CountdownEvent` object in any scenario where you have some specific count of operations, tasks, events, etc. that should occur before some specific thread should continue after waiting.

Of course, not all synchronization scenarios involve this kind of requirement. There are other, different synchronization mechanisms that can be used for those other scenarios. The `CountdownEvent` is specifically for those scenarios where the waiting of a thread is unblocked by the completion of a countdown, hence the name of the class.

Comment: whatever i understand the program that 5 thread start job in loop one after one in for loop. AddCount() and Signal() just increment and decrement a counter but which line help to sync the thread not clear. e.Wait(); force main thread to wait until all child thread task is completed.

Comment: above program start multiple thread means start 5 thread from loop and sleep() simulate long running operation when sleep() for each thread completed then `Signal()` decrement a counter. what is the motto of this kind of program ? if possible please come with right sample code to understand the significance of usage for `Signal() & AddCount()` and tell me how it help the thread synchronization and a program because the above program can be written without `Signal() & AddCount()` feature. need guideline.

Comment: Synchronization of the threads occurs because of the call to `Wait()`. I.e., the five worker threads run freely and independently of each other; the main thread is caused to wait for the five worker threads to complete. As is the case with any of the higher-level synchronization objects, it is true you could write the program without using `CountdownEvent`. But it's not possible to write the program without _some_ synchronization object/feature, and in this example `CountdownEvent` offers a simpler and easier mechanism than the alternatives.

Comment: tell me all other classes name which does the same job .Net framework.

Comment: The `Monitor` class (used by the C# `lock` statement) forms the basis for most uses of synchronization in .NET. You can implement any other synchronization object with a combination of the `Monitor` and other variables. E.g. to implement `CountdownEvent`, you could use `lock`, an integer counter variable, and the `Wait()` and `Pulse()` methods in `Monitor`. It is not practical for me to literally name _"all other classes"_ that could be used for this sort of purpose.

Comment: thanks.  AutoResetEvent & ManualResetEvent classes used for the same purpose?

Comment: no race condition would not occur if multiple thread try to access same things? if u see the my sample program which run 5 thread freely but if the same 5 thread would try to access a same variable then race condition may occur....am i right. in that case how to handle the situation like at a time one thread would access any resource and when done then next thread can access and other thread would wait to get access. can u tell me how to design thread code in that way? if possible can u plzz come with a sample program. thanks

Comment: Auto/ManualResetEvent can be used for synchronization as well. They provide "checkpoint" semantics, rather than "critical section" as `lock` does, but either kind of synchronization can be built from the other. You are right that five freely-running threads are not synchronized with _each other_; if they've a shared resource, you need additional synchronization (e.g. `lock`) to protect the use of the resource. There's a plethora of sample code showing correct use of `lock`. You should start with [the MSDN pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c5kehkcz(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: nice url is this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396   thanks a lot @Peter.